# java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out, Tomcat 7 and iptables

Tags: mysql, tomcat7, firewall, iptables, connection-timeout

I am experiencing a weird problem..

Basically our Java developer said that in the java application the services that access the db to write on it get this error:

java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:394)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:529)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:233)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:306)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:323)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:970)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:911)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:836)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1172)
at rab.server.system.rpc.MailServiceComponents.sendFeedback(MailServiceComponents.java:259)
at rab.server.homepage.rpc.HomepageServiceImpl.createFeedback(HomepageServiceImpl.java:61)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor31.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Instead services that just read from the db, work like a charm...

After some attempts, I tried to disabled the firewall, it worked. Then I tried to load a basic configuration:

```
:~# cat /etc/iptables.test.rules 
*filter

# Allows all loopback (lo0) traffic and drop all traffic to 127/8 that doesn't use lo0
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT

# Accepts all established inbound connections
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allows all outbound traffic
# You could modify this to only allow certain traffic
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT

# Allows HTTP and HTTPS connections from anywhere (the normal ports for websites)
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

# Allows SSH connections for script kiddies
# THE -dport NUMBER IS THE SAME ONE YOU SET UP IN THE SSHD_CONFIG FILE
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Now you should read up on iptables rules and consider whether ssh access 
# for everyone is really desired. Most likely you will only allow access from certain     IPs.

# Allow ping
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT

# log iptables denied calls (access via 'dmesg' command)
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7

# Reject all other inbound - default deny unless explicitly allowed policy:
-A INPUT -j REJECT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT

COMMIT
```

And this worked too. Now, the problem is that after I loaded this basic configuration, our server factory start complained because in their configuration, they have rules for their monitoring and backupping services (and they are so many..). After some attempts modifying their rules to check where the problem lies.. I discovered that the critical difference between mine and their is the policy in the OUTPUT (ACCEPT vs DROP).

So here I am, I need to find the right rule to add to them config, keeping the OUTPUT policy on DROP.

I would like to underline that Tomcat 7 is serving properly the webapp and that mysql is listening as follow:

```
~# netstat -lnp | grep mysql
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19356/mysqld    
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     HÖRT         669292   19356/mysqld        /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

I tried to add to their config many things like for example:

```
 iptables -A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

And many other, without success...

Any idea?

Comment: should be on serverfault.  this isn't a dev question, it's a provisioning question.

Comment: Ah ok, i will post it then there, thank